# PrintWriter eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse to write code that needs to write to an output file. the file name comes from a command-line argument. I don't know where it is creating the file. It says that my workspace is the default for the output file but it is no where to be found. This is my code

```
try{
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new File(args[3]));
    //System.out.print(args[3]);
    output.append('l');
    output.close();
} catch(IOException e) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need third command line argument? If not, I would suggest you to have a look on this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html---- When you run 'java Echo Drink Hot Java' command it has only 3 arguments... Drink Hot Java not 5...

Comment: yes i need the third command line argument because in the project this is how it is stated. args[3] will have the filename of the output file

Comment: Then you must edit your question, and provide the exception details... At this moment I would recommend you to add e.printStackTrace() statement before exit(0)... Though it is not a good practice to use System.exit...

Comment: The exception is a non issue for this project because they said they were not going to try to break the code by giving it wrong input. I guess the problem i am having is my file that should be created by printwriter is no where to be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your program to see the absolute path of the file.

```
File file = new File(args[3]);
System.err.println( "File: " + file.getAbsolutePath() );
```

Comment: File: /Users/kfish/Documents/workspace/CMSC202/output.txt

That is what i got and where it should be but i cannot find this file. it is not physically in my workspace

Comment: i found it, kind of. its in a place where i can view it but do you know why it is not shown in eclipse when i created it?

Comment: You did not refresh your project.

Comment: I did refresh it and it is still not in my workspace but it is okay because it is somewhere i can get to it so i don't care. thanks though.